# How can I make some of the Items in ExpandableListView Not Expandable

Tags: java, android, fragment, expandablelistview, submenu

I am writing a navigation system using the `ExpandableListView` widget, and I am able to have expandable lists, that function properly, but what about items in the navigation that have no submenus like `Home` and just transition straight to the Home Fragment? All of the Group Items appear as dropdown-able even though they don't have any children. Can I take away the dropdown icon from the parents that don't have children? Or can I only either, have Icons or not have icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the expanding of the group items, you could set a GroupClickListener and return true if you want to disable the expansion.

```
ExpandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                              int groupPosition, long id) { 
     return groupPosition == 0; //Index of item in your list that you want to be expandable
  }
});
```

As for the icons, you could define your own layout for the group items.

Comment: That won't however remove the indicators from the childless groups.

Comment: @user3249477 I figured it out though... Just set the icon to null on the expandable list view! Works like a charm

Comment: That removes it from all items. Kinda not what you asked for but what ever :-)

Comment: @danieljohngomez .. hi yes it works, but i have a question .. if i have a expandable listview and it has 10 items and 5 of them have sub items and rest of them does not have any sub item they just navigate to other activities when we touched them, so how can we create this type of expandable list view.  in this solution we can return only one position please help